# Appending new column after UDF to existing PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, pyspark, bigdata

I have the following example dataframe.

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| data1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|1      |abc     |abd     |3       |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|3      |abd     |abd     |3       |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|2      |abe     |abg     |2       |
```

I am applying a UDF that converts data 4 in to `True` if 3 and `False` if 2, for example.

I am using the following code to generate an independent DataFrame with the old and new values in a column:

```
UDF = udf(converterFnc,StringType())
tempDF = mydata.select('data 4', UDF('data 4').alias('newdata 4'))
```

and getting the following DataFrame:

```
+--------+-----------+
| data 4 | newdata 4 |
+--------+-----------+
| 3      | True      |
+--------+-----------+
| 2      | False     |
```

I am trying to figure out how to merge this back to the original data frame, but I find that I get a weird issue using `join` in which all of the joined values are just the first value for the entire dataframe.

My desired output:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| data1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 | newdata 4 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|1      |abc     |abd     |3       | True      |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|3      |abd     |abd     |3       | True      |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|2      |abe     |abg     |2       | False     |
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` and `when.otherwise` to create a new column without the `joining` process:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("newdata 4", F.when(df["data 4"] == 3, True).otherwise(F.when(df["data 4"] == 2, False))).show()
+-----+------+------+------+---------+
|data1|data 2|data 3|data 4|newdata 4|
+-----+------+------+------+---------+

|    1|   abc|   abd|     3|     true|
|    3|   abd|   abd|     3|     true|
|    2|   abe|   abg|     2|    false|
+-----+------+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks! My method was a little more convoluted than just a simple `True/False` classifier but the `withColumn` method I was able to get it to work!

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps!